# How much $ to calculate for an Editor

Tags: editing, getting-started

I plan to self publish a book (non fiction). Currently I have 150.000 characters, but when it's done I will end up with around 250.000. I am not a native english speaker but write the book in english, so I want to pay somebody to edit my book. Although my target audience are software developers, it is an "pretty easy" read for everybody. It is basically non-technical, more explaining "how to" work instead of "how to solve technical problems".

I have learned you can have an editor in two ways:

1. Editors for proof reading, grammar correction etc only
2. Editors who does 1) plus giving tipps on improving the readability, caring on logical errors etc

I have already learned how I might find a [native speaking editor](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2529/how-do-i-find-an-affordable-editor). I would like to calculate the expenses for my book but do not know how much an Editor takes for such a job and how long it would take to complete it. Some raw estimations from your experience would be great.

**UPDATE:**

Because comments to this question explained me that nobody calculates in Characters (except me :-)), I counted words:

The current document has around 30.000 words, but I expect around 50.000 when it is ready. When I copy the text into Word for Mac, it shows me 49 pages. I tend to think they will become around 90 when I am done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet is to get some quotes.

I realize that sounds like I'm dodging the question, but I'm not. My method, for example, is to work on a manuscript for one hour and use that as gauge to estimate the rest of the work. For some writers, that's 15 pages an hour; for others it's 30. So my quote for the "15 pages an hour" person is twice as much as the other one.

Some editors have flat rates: $50 an hour, 50 cents a page. Some will charge you by the project: $800 no matter how long it takes.

You won't know unless you start asking for estimates from actual editors who might work with you. I couldn't give you an estimate for your non-fiction ESL work without looking at it.

Comment: Well, i upvoted and accepted this even when I have no clue about the price ranges :-| I have expected more of "something between $500 and $1000" or maybe "up to $5000". Anyway, it already helped me to learn that there is so much difference in the rates and I know now that I need to ask for many quotes. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you're particularly price sensitive don't forget that using an online editor upfront can save you money. These automated editing programs are generally free/cheap compared to a human editor and can pick up a lot of the stuff that an editor would. They leave the editor to concentrate their time on stylist issues rather than grammar, word usage, and structure.
Take a look at (in no particular order):
http://autocrit.com
http://prowritingaid.com
http://masteredit.net
Good luck!

Comment: Great websites, thank you for sharing them. I will definitely go with one as it will also help me with blogging, where a "in person" editor is not possible.