# Where do I go looking for an editor?

Tags: editing, short-story

I have several completed short stories, and I'm considering having them line-edited before I submit them.

But I have no idea where to look for editors. How do I know who's any good? Where do I look, and what do I look for?

Comment: There "where do I look?" part seems like it would be covered by [How do I find an affordable editor?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/2529/2533)

Comment: Try this website, i don't know much about looking for an editor but i found this website that looks like it might help https://www.thecreativepenn.com/2014/07/14/how-to-find-the-right-editor/

Comment: I think the question confuses Editor and Copy Editor.  Which one are you looking for?

Comment: @Andrey: For a line-editor, as I wrote. [Here's](http://victoriamixon.com/editing-terminology/) an explanation, defining developmental editing, line editing, and copy editing.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to find an editor is through word of mouth.  This is why it's valuable to become part of your local writing community.  Writing itself is a solitary endeavor but being a writer benefits from being in the society of writers.

Are there writing centers near you where you could attend events with other writers?  Is there an opportunity to join a writing group?

Once one starts meeting other writers, things such as editor recommendations come easily.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of editors and beta-readers available on fiverr.com for reasonable rates.

Comment: You might want to consider expanding on your answer to address the OP's other concerns: "*How do I know who's any good? ... what do I look for?*"

Comment: Can you recommend several sites, or give a link to somewhere that covers alternatives? As this stands, it's coming over a bit like an advertisement.

Comment: Reviewing low quality posts, I did not edit this one to add the following, but as a fiverr user myself I'd add the following user endorsement (not advertisement): Vendors are reviewed and rated by their customers; the interface makes it difficult (not impossible) to avoid rating your vendor. Most have $5 rates for some small amount of work, maybe an hour. So you can provide a sample of some pages and see if their work is what you expect. And often, from their self-description and messages you exchange, you can tell if they are a native speaker of your language and can edit their own writing.